Unable to confirm transaction with python
while I implement swap spl token in python with solana library
It was start appear when I change my rpc to alchemy free rpc
solana.rpc.core.UnconfirmedTxError: Unable to confirm transaction 4EJLQMUUkxuGiCeuqCQCNLpRXjd8XRTdCNnYnmCYbhZa1Z4FuJoNszn6Wg3Ybd2XPKEuyy38EWFFBFJwLjyKPv9u

in my code
        swap_tx = Transaction()
        if WSOL_token_account_Instructions != None:
            recent_blockhash = solana_client.get_latest_blockhash(commitment="confirmed")
            swap_tx.recent_blockhash = recent_blockhash.value.blockhash
            swap_tx.add(WSOL_token_account_Instructions)

        #Modify Compute Unit Limit and Price Accordingly  to your Gas Preferences
        swap_tx.add(instructions_swap,set_compute_unit_price(252320),set_compute_unit_limit(2003370))
        swap_tx.add(closeAcc)
        # Execute Transaction
        txn = solana_client.send_transaction(swap_tx, payer)
        txid_string_sig = txn.value
        if txid_string_sig:
            print("Transaction sent")
            # print(f"Transaction Signature Waiting to be confirmed: https://solscan.io/tx/{txid_string_sig}")
            print("Waiting Confirmation")

        confirmation_resp = solana_client.confirm_transaction(
            txid_string_sig,
            commitment=Confirmed,
            sleep_seconds=1.5,
        )

Is it have problem in rpc or my code?
Can you give me some advice?
Or are there any python example to swap spl token with solana?

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
